# how to implement javascript "star" function of Google search result page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When in Google search result, in each entry of search result, there is a "star" nearby, and end user could click the star to indicate whether the result is good or not. I believe this function is implemented in Javascript.

My question is, I want to implement a similar function in my own web application. Which is there is one "star" in a page for each entry (i.e. 5 stars if there are 5 entries), and user could click the "star" to indicate whether the entry is good or not. Any sample code to implement this function?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://nofunc.org/AJAX_Star_Rating/